# Dropdown function on attributes // Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filter, attributes

I am looking to find a way to filter through attributes in woocommerce. I run a wine webshop and I want my customers to able to find the wines more quickly.

Currently I have configured both country and region as attributes. Ideally this would show up as a dropdown filter with country as a parent attribute and the regions acting as children.

As is:

[situation as-is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Zuk.png)

Desired:

[desired situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1NP8.png)

How can I achieve this in woocommerce?

Comment: Hi!! Have you tried the filters for Woocommerce that you can find in Widgets?

Comment: Yes, they work for categories but not for attributes. Both country and region are attributes. By using the default widgets, they are shown separately. I want them to show in a drop-down : Country > Region.